# First and last transaction date for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, aggregate-functions

I want to display the first and last record for each day regardless of what has been sold. Basically, the first and last transaction time of each day.

Sample sales data:

```
product_id |product_name |date
1232       |laptop       |06/08/2019 17:05:57
1233       |telephone    |06/08/2019 16:05:57
1234       |laptop       |06/08/2019 15:05:47
1235       |laptop       |05/05/2019 05:05:22
1236       |laptop       |05/05/2019 03:05:21
1237       |telephone    |05/05/2019 20:05:20
1238       |telephone    |07/08/2019 01:06:09
1239       |laptop       |07/08/2019 05:05:59
1240       |telephone    |07/08/2019 20:05:37
1241       |laptop       |07/08/2019 23:05:29
```

Result:

```
product_id|product_name|date
1234      |laptop      |06/08/2019 15:05:47
1232      |laptop      |06/08/2019 17:05:57
1236      |laptop      |05/05/2019 03:05:21
1237      |telephone   |05/05/2019 20:05:20
1238      |telephone   |07/08/2019 01:06:09
1241      |laptop      |07/08/2019 23:05:29
```

Tried Query:

```
select 
product_id,
product_name,
MAX(date),
MIN(date)
FROM sales_data
WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(date)
GROUP BY product_id, product_name
```

Comment: What is the issue with your tried query? Remove `where` condition and properly convert `date` and you should return min and max for each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is window functions:

```
select sd.*
from (select sd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date::date order by date asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by date::date order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from sales_data sd
     ) sd
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

However, `distinct on` with `union all` might perform better with a index eson `(date::date, date)` and `(date::date, date desc)`:

```
(select distinct on (date::date) sd.*
 from sales_data sd
 order by date::date, date asc
)
union all
(select distinct on (date::date) sd.*
 from sales_data sd
 order by date::date, date desc
);
```